# create two-dimensional array

Tags: javascript

I'm new. I have an array

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6]
```

I want to get a two-dimensional array from it

```
[[0, 0, 0,0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,]]
```

how to do this  without regular expressions

I have a solution where I use regular expressions with the split method, but  need a variant without regular expressions and so that you get an array of zeros, not a string of zeros

```
    function zeroGroups(arr){
        const allZerosGroups = arr
          .map(item => item !== 0 ? '-' : 0)
          .join('')
          .split(/[^0]/)
          .filter(item => item.length !== 0)
          
        return allZerosGroups
    }
console.log(zeroGroups([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6])) // [ '0000', '0000000' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through and check along the way. This is one way to do it:

```
var arr =  [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6]
    var container = []
    containerCount = 0
    arrCount = 0
    var dArr = []
    arrLen = arr.length
    loop1:
    for (i = 0;i< arrLen;i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {                                                              
            dArr[arrCount] = arr[i]  
            arrCount++    
            console.log(dArr)                 
        } else if (arrCount == 0) {
            continue
        } else {
            container[containerCount] = dArr                        
            arrCount = 0
            containerCount++    
            dArr = []                
        }                
    }

    console.log(container)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope, this helps.

```js
let arr1 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6];

let res = [];
let temp = []; 

arr1.map((item)=>{
  if(item === 0){temp.push(item)}
  else {
    if (temp.length!=0){
      res.push(temp); 
      temp = [];
    }
  }
 });

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You should use `forEach`, not `map`, since you're not interested in `map`'s return value.

Comment: This'll also produce the wrong result if `arr1` ends with a `0`.

Comment: Nice @deceze - I couldn't catch that. In that case I should have also added 1 more scenario if no more length is present // end of array & current item is still '0'. Thanks man.